# Error al crear un nuevo proyecto en Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
    be found here:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3

C:\Sites>
```

Cuando Creo un nuevo proyecto hace todo esto y al final me dice que hay un error con sqlite3, he intentado de todo pero no logro resolverlo, no he podido levantar el servidor, ¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de hallar la respuesta, en este blog `https://mycodeissuesandfixes.blogspot.com/2019/02/error-al-crear-nuevo-proyecto-en-ruby.html`explican detalladamente la solución, exactamente en la parte final donde dicen Solución final